# Magento 1.9, getting 404 on category pages after renaming Store Name

Tags: magento-1.9

Im struggling on this so i need help please, i have 2 websites on the same magento installation ( 1.9.3.8 ) :

CANADA ( default, code : base )
English (store view code : en_ca ) 
French ( store view code : fr_ca )

USA ( code : usa )
English ( store view code : en_us )

Add store code to url : yes
Use web server rewrites : yes

the default website was the Canada one, but we decide to use USA as default, so i did this on dev ( i have no production site yet, still in dev mode ) :

Delete the USA website ( do you want to create a DB backup - i answer NO ) 
now i have the default website only ( canada with 2 languages ),
I rename the Website name to USA ( keeping code to : base ),
I rename the Store Name to USA store,
I rename the Store view from en_ca to en_us,
i delete the fr_ca store view.

After that i create my new website Canada with previous deleted settings, i reassign all my CMS pages and static blocks the the new Website, reindex, clear cache.

Everyting work except the USA - default(en_us) categories, it gives me a 404 ( not cms page 404, the default magento ugly blue & orange one ). All my products and CMS pages are working good.

What ive done since, i create a second store view in default website ( en_us2 ), this one work, i also create another root category and assign it to the USA Store, keep having this 404.

So it look like the default store view categories are down for some reason i did.

is there anyone that have face this issue before and/or have maybe a solution ?

thank you

Comment: did you reindex ?

Comment: Yes i reindex couple times, clear cache also.

Comment: What you think if you remove all (not just rename) the websites, stores, store views then you restart from scratch but you have to set all your sms pages for the different websites

Comment: @Prince, thank you for your help, i did that also. At this point i got only Default Website( base ) - default store( usa store ) - default store view( en_us )... and it was still not working.

Comment: Check in magento database names , delete or change them

Answer (score 0):

So i decide to return to previous settings and reinstall a back up( files + DB ), all work good. So i try the same procedure that broke the site, but in a reverse order, i rename : store view - store name - website, instead of : website - store name - store view... not sure if this was the problem, but it work find.

Cheers